# float on element effecting sibling elements height , Wy?

Tags: html, css

i was just trying to build my own custom search box , and i have almost succeed , i have kept the code quite clean and neat , have a look :

HTML :

```
<div class="inline-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-addon">0.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.inline-form >* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 20em;
    background: pink;
}
.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group-addon {
    width: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-addon:first-child {
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px
}
.input-group .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group > .form-control {
    width: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-control {
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.input-group-addon:last-child {
    width: auto;
    border-left: 0px none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE ::](http://jsfiddle.net/u01nm0ny/1/)** - Works perfectly fine ..

now if i remove the `float:left` from `.input-group > .form-control` something really messy happens , have a look at the screen shot below :

[image]

Why does that happen ? why is float on `.form-control` effecting its sibling elements ?

**P.S.** : My code works just fine , i just want to know why this happens in CSS ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: I disagree **strongly** on that with @humble.rumble. Using float for layout purposes may often be difficult (mostly if the person who makes use of it doesn't fully understand floating), but it is perfectly valid and from my point of view still the preferred layouting method in most cases.

Comment: While there may be issues with floats when it comes to old browsers, inline-block has much more problematic issues related to unwanted white-space which you omit to mention here. Both layout methods have their ups and downs, and deciding on which to use imho is a case-by-case decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is float on .form-control effecting its sibling elements ?

You have the setting `font-size: 20em` applied to the selector `.inline-form >*`. In CSS the `line-height` property of a parent when inherited by `block` elements the `containing block` inherits the property, whereas when the property is inherited by inline elements the `line-box` inherits the property. This is why the `div` elements expand to the full height of the parent and the `input` element did not.

Setting `line-height: initial` on the parent of the block element will cancel the inheritance.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/u01nm0ny/5/))

```
.input-group {
    line-height: initial;
}
```

#### Specification Document Excerpts

What is a line-box?

> #### 9.4.2 Inline formatting context
>
> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally,
>   one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing
>   block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between
>   these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their
>   bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them
>   may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form
>   a line is called a `line box`.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visuren.html#line-box

How is line-height calculated for inline vs block elements?

> #### 10.8.1 Leading and half-leading
>
> ...
>
> On a block container element
>   whose content
>   is composed of inline-level
>   elements, 'line-height' specifies the *minimal* height of line boxes
>   within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above
>   the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each
>   line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the
>   element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary
>   box a "strut." (The name is inspired by TeX.).
>
> ...
>
> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height'
>   specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box
>   height.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

Comment: i think your 2nd point is wrong , vertical align , is in relation to the parents baseline ?

Comment: it will be great if you can add that to your answer and also add a link to the doc's .

Answer (score 2):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

... So in general, when you float an element, you are taking it out of it's normal flow. It will change it's position based on it's container element... So if you have more items in this container then you may need to apply relevant css for these as well, for example `clear:both;`.

Comment: fantastic , but was yet looking for a more contextual answer !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I take it that the "messy" part in your screen shot is the input box overflowing to the right? If so, that is the `width: 100%;` for `.input-group > .form-control` (on Chrome).

Comment: @sorrry , i has attached the wroung screen shot .. check now !

Comment: @connexo your totally right ! , but its my humble request to still get a more contextual answre !

Answer (score 2):

The specific answer you are looking for comes here. You need to memorize that.

When an element floats, it is no longer being taken into consideration for the browser calculation of the height of its parent element. Take this example of a `<ul>` with floated `<li>` inside it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul').on('click', function() {
       alert($(this).height()+"px");
   });
});
```

```css
ul.floating-children {
  background-color: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.floating-children > li {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

.floating-children > li.not-floating {
   float: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Click on the list to see height.</h1>

<ul class="floating-children">
  <li>You will</li>
  <li>not see</li>
  <li>red background</li>
  <li>of parent &lt;ul&gt;</li>
</ul>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<ul class="floating-children last-child-not-floating">
  <li>You will</li>
  <li><del>not</del> see</li>
  <li>red background</li>
  <li class="not-floating">of parent &lt;ul&gt;</li>
</ul>
```

Actually, as a side note it might be interesting that the jQuery click handler on the first list only ever triggers because of "event bubbling". Since the first `<ul>` has a height of zero, it is actually *unclickable*, but the click on its child `<li>` bubbles to the parent.

Comment: and than comes the clearfix hack right ? haha  , great answer nevertheless ! , +1 , but my question is still unanswered , i'll apply your logic to my example and if applicable , i'll accept your answer ! :D

Comment: Exactly. clearfix serves only one purpose, and that is to make parent elements "contain" their floating children, which basically means nothing other than "taking floating children into consideration when calculating height".

Comment: And even if in this case you're unable to apply this to your code, you still have the option to +1 - which in this case would mean upvoting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle without using float http://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/p3f6xzr6/1/

### Explanation:

'float:left' is doing right thing as it should be but `display: table-cell` is the responsible for such behavior.  `display: table-cell` property makes all child's div in a equal height depending on highest siblings div. Change it to `display: inline-block` and apply necessary padding and then remove your `float:left`, it will work expectedly.

`float:left` Simply wraps your `.input-group-addon` div and overwrite/cancel  full height behaviour of the   `display: table-cell` and made your work success.  In fact in your case `display: table-cell` is useless since you are using `float:left` which simply overwrite table-cell height properties